# Git using the wrong credentials when gcloud is used as a helper

Tags: windows, git, gcloud

My setup is Visual Studio Code on windows 10. I have installed Git for windows and would like to use Google Cloud Repositories in Visual Studio Code.

I have set up the credential helper to be gcloud.md. I made sure the correct project/id is selected in gcloud.

When I push the changes to Google repository i get the message

> fatal: remote error: Access denied to zzz@zzz.com

The message is correct the user does not have access. But the user is not the active user in gcloud. But I would expect the active user in gcloud to be used for the authentication.

How can I use gcloud as the credentials helper and authenticate with the different available gcloud users?

Comment: Executing git credential-manager clear and then gcloud auth login does change the authenticated user. As a workaround I am using that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `gcloud source repos clone` gcloud is added as a credential helper for that repository. It is configured to always use the gcloud account that was active when you cloned the repo (since that is the account that would have access and that presumably you would want to use from that point on). So regardless of your current gcloud settings, opertaions on that repo will continue to use that account.

You can see this if you run:

`git config credential.helper`

from within that repo. It will print the gcloud command that runs, and it should have a `--account` flag pointing to a specific account.

If you want to change the account, you can change your gcloud account and clone the repo again, or you can use `git config` to edit that credential helper setting and put whatever account you intended.